prove that the column vector is left quasi regular.
I want to prove that $M_n(J(R))\subset J(M_nR)$:
the following is my approach:
let $R$ be a ring, $M_1=[m_{ij}]\in Mat_nJ(R)$ where $J(R)$ is jacobson radical of $R$, I want to show two fact:
$1.$if $m_{ij}=0$ for $j\neq1$ then $M_1$ is left quasi-regular.(in other words, the collection of this form is left quasi regular left ideal.)
$2.$ Since $M_n(J(R))=M_1+...M_n$, and each is left quasi regular, so we get $M_n(J(R))$ is also left quasi regular.
For the first step, I know that from left quasi regular definition,  there exist $r_i\in R$ such that $r_i+m_i+r_im_i=0$ . However, for the matrix form, for example,$$
\qquad \qquad 
M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
m_{11} & 0 &  0 \\
m_{21} & 0 &  0 \\
m_{31} & 0 &  0
\end{bmatrix}$$
then how can I find a matrix $$
\qquad \qquad 
N_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
m'_{11} & 0 &  0 \\
m'_{21} & 0 &  0 \\
m'_{31} & 0 &  0
\end{bmatrix}$$
,such that $M_1$ is left quasi regular
